# Push notification in xamarin cross platform

Tags: xamarin, push-notification

I would like to add a Push Notification to a Xamarin Cross Platform application.

My application has MaterDetailPage on the Portable layer. When a notification comes in, I want it to appear as "Messages (1)" in the menu.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it in cross platfrom, you'll have to implement some custom renderers, as Google and Apple have different ways to implement that.

A nice component for implementing that is https://components.xamarin.com/view/azure-messaging but rememeber that you'll also have to do some backend work.

Regardless of how you decide to implement push notifications, if you intent to develop for iOS I would recomend reading https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote_notifications_in_ios/ as you'll probably have some trouble with the certificates/provisioning.

Comment: FirebaseCloudMessaging would work to. It is available as Xamarin compatible package...